# ES6 (React) in Chrome debugger not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools

[image: Chrome-Screen-shot]

Hi there, as you may see in the screen capture. I have a snippet of javascript code (ES6/React) opening in the latest Chrome (66.0.3359.170) developer tool.

Part of the code shown correctly as Javascript Code, however from line 31, the code looks like some kind of plain text and there is no way to inspect into the inputs and variables.

Anyone know how to fix it? BTW, latest FireFox works fine in my environment.

Thanks

[image: FireFox-Screen-Shot]

Comment: in what way is the *debugger* not working? is there some debugging functionality that's broken? or is it just that the syntax highlighting isn't pretty?

Comment: in my case, source map will map the "translated" JavaScript to the original ES6 code. And even you put the breakpoint on the "translated" output, the Chrome debugger will still go to your original ES6 code

Answer (score 1):

The backticks  are messing up with the highlighting in the editor.

If the code is correct and runs fine, then string templates are possibly not correctly supported by the editor.

(Note: By 'editor' I mean the visualizer part of Chrome Developer Tools)

The code contains JSX expressions and it is very unlikely it would directly appear in Chrome Developer Tools. This code should not be directly executed but elaborated by React and turned into final html and Javascript.... In other words it does not belong there.

Comment: I don't think it's an editor, it's Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: I mean by the Chrome Developer Tools editor (visualizer)

Comment: I think it's actually the React `{ ... }` stuff that's confusing it.

Comment: it should't though... either way the code seems fine. it looks like a parsing/highlighting bug

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

In my case, the first issue that I cannot hover over the variables, usually you will see variable inspections when you hover over it. So the code works fine but the debugger is not working correctly. 

Meanwhile, I realized I can debug the JSX line by line in FireFox, seems Chrome doesn't support it yet? or just my environment?